# Unzip content and concatenate the contents into a file

Tags: batch-file

I have 50k zipped files in a folder. I need to unzip all these content, concatenate all into 1 single file and delete all the zipped files. I am trying to unzip content without the need to have a new unzipped file which I will have to end up deleting. The following is an equivalent operation I currently do in Linux which works.

```
for f in *.zip;
do
unzip -p "${f}" >> concatenatedfile.txt;
rm $f;
done;
```

But I need to do this in windows via Batch and I am limited to using 7z for unzipping.

Currently using following code where I am hard coding the text filename for testing purposes and it works. I am trying to obtain this file name dynamically and if possible not create this file at all and just obtain zip file data and keep adding to the concatenatedfile.txt file.

```
for %%z in (*.zip) do (
    7z e "%%~fz" > NUL: 
    type hardcoded_filename.txt >> concatenatedfile.txt
    del hardcoded_filename.txt
    del %%z
)
```

Comment: You have to do a second for loop within the first to pick up the extracted filename.

Comment: @Noodles A second loop even though it is just a single file in each loop? Can I get an example please.

Comment: So are you saying that the text file inside the zip file is not the same name?

Comment: Make your output file name concatenated.log. Then use a wildcard *.txt for your type and delete commands.

Comment: I know winzip has the functionality to read a file inside a zip file. I would assume 7zip has a command line option for that as well.

Comment: @Squashman A simple solution that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
For %%A in (*.vbs) Do (
    Copy "%%A" "%%A.bak
    For %%B in (*.bak) Do (
        Echo %%B
        Del "%%B"
    )
)
```

Comment: What does the code in this answer have to do with unzip?

Comment: Hm didn't know asking someone nicely using the word please equates to begging. And answering @Pang with my quote, confused much?